# Remove a Resource from an Outlook Appointment

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-web-addins

In my O365/Outlook add-in, using the Office JavaScript API, I am trying to manage attendees and resources.

`Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.getAsync`
and 
`Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.setAsync`
has worked well for me so far, however Outlook will take email addresses that are set up as resource calendars and resolve them as resources.
Once this happens I can't seem to access or manipulate them.

`Office.context.mailbox.item.resources` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources are not supported in Compose currently. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page.

It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the [existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13316001-add-office-javascript-api-support-for-resources-of). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.